# how to create image over image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do two things to different images in the same page, I looked all over and I can't find answer, I'd like it if someone could help me.

In the first image I want to put over it a smaller image on the side of it and on hover the big image the small image changes and a caption appears.

In addition in the second image I want that a smaller image will appear always and if you hover on the big image a border of the image appear and the the words under the image appear will be painted in different  color.

thank you

Comment: The problem is that i dont know how to set the small image over the big one

Comment: We're not here to write code for you, and you have shown no evidence of anything you have tried. Despite this, I will give you a clue as to where to look... You should look at using CSS and in particular the `position` attibute using the `relative` vs. `absolute` values, and then the `top`,`right`,`bottom` and `left` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set bigger z-index via javascript on hover action on that element you are hovering. Position of smaller image and some text over another element can be made e.g. using position: absolute; and z-index (via javascript/jquery).

Comment: I wrote the code for imege over image and use z index the problem is that i dont know how to change the small image to anther on hover

Comment: you can use img + img to target the image following the other, and add a :hover ex(img:hover + img) to change it on hover :)

Comment: set the small image in the default state e.g. smallimage { display: none; } and then on hover add class to smallimage active and in css write .smallimage.active { display: block; }. Do not forget to remove the active class before you add it. so first removeClass('active') and then addClass('active'). There are of course other ways how to achieve this. Check this link http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/ it's a little different what you want, however you will get the idea.